# 'No Primary Key' error with INNER JOIN query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, join, jdbc, primary-key

The thing is, both tables do have primary keys, and I haven't had any problems so far with any other standard SELECTS/INSERTS at all. I'm new to JOINS, but I can't see why this isn't working.

I'm get this error message:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No primary key found for table devicetable.
```

However, the primary keys for both tables are the columns I'm selecting for: `deviceid` / `username`. Perhaps this has something to do with it?

I'm accessing it via JDBC

```
PreparedStatement query = curSQL.getConn().prepareStatement("SELECT devicetable.pushid FROM devicetable, usertable WHERE usertable.username=? AND usertable.deviceid = devicetable.deviceid", ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
query.setString(1, username);
ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();

if (rs.next()){
    rs.updateString("pushid", pushID);
    rs.updateRow();
}

rs.close();
query.close();
```

With the SQL:

```
SELECT devicetable.pushid FROM devicetable, usertable
WHERE  usertable.username=?
AND    usertable.deviceID = devicetable.deviceID
```

Comment: Have you tried using an explicit join? `FROM devicetable JOIN usertable ON usertable.deviceID = devicetable.deviceID` and remove the `usertable.deviceid = devicetable.deviceid` part from the WHERE clause.

Comment: That's worked ! Put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Funny, I originally had that down as an answer (hence the timestamp on my answer) but I chose to delete it and go for a comment instead. Anyway, I undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an explicit join:

```
SELECT devicetable.pushid
FROM devicetable
JOIN usertable ON usertable.deviceID = devicetable.deviceID
WHERE usertable.username = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

The JOIN clause in a SELECT has nothing to do whatsoever with primary keys. You don't need to have a primary key defined for **any** SELECT query.

A side effect may be that you get duplicate rows, but that is a different matter entirely.

Actually, there is **no** explicit JOIN in your query. You could rewrite your query with an explicit JOIN like this equivalent:

```
SELECT devicetable.pushid
FROM   devicetable
JOIN   usertable USING (deviceID)
WHERE  usertable.username=?
```

Read more about the [JOIN syntax in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM).